# What is the most professional name for "squiggly bracket"?

Tags: terminology, braces

I am creating a software training video and need to refer to these brackets:

> { }

I usually call them "squiggly brackets" or "curly brackets".

Is there a more professional name?

Comment: Related: [Bracket vs brace](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3379/575)

Comment: I have read all the answers, but I think that "squiggly" is so much cooler than "curly" that that is what I shall use from now on. I shall blog, write authoritative textbooks and popular novels, and a decade from now it will be the new and undisputed standard.

Comment: What's the point of resurrecting this question?!

Comment: @rudra - The stackexchange automatically reprints old questions to the front page.  There are details about how/why this is done in one of the general FAQ pages.

Comment: @mickeyf If you like *squiggly brackets*, then I promise you that you’ll enjoy *squirrelly brackets* even more, which are kinda like *curly brackets* but squirrellier.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think *curly brackets* is the most professional name. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets_.7B_.7D) for more details.

Comment: yes, from the wiki page, I agree: "Therefore, when it is necessary to avoid any possibility of confusion, such as in computer programming, it may be best to use the term curly bracket rather than brace."

Comment: @Edward: just so you know, the "most professional name" remains "braces". In case that matter. "Curly bracket" is very uncommon in programming books.

Comment: I agree. In British English, "curly brackets" is the most technically correct name. "Braces" may or may not even be understood!

Comment: I use "curly braces" for my american english programming needs

Comment: To add another American perspective: {} are braces, [] are brackets, () are parentheses, <> are less-than and greater-than (or angle brackets, if you must), and «» are chevrons.

Comment: To add a slight correction to @skst, ⟨ ⟩ are angle brackets, and < > are less-than and greater-than signs.

Comment: @PeterShor, I did say those are less-than and greater-than signs. I added the "angle bracket" parenthetical because that's what many developers call them, especially given their additional purpose in programming languages (that of bracketing something). The symbols  you entered as angle brackets don't display in Chrome or Notepad++; they do display in Firefox and Visual Studio. However, they're not valid syntax in any programming language I'm familiar with, so I doubt many developers would confuse them for "angle brackets."

Comment: skst's list is what I've always understood to be the correct terms. "angle brackets" seems to be a fairly recent invention, I presume since the advent of HTML and XML. I have sometimes heard people use "curly braces" or "curly brackets" for braces, and "square brackets" for brackets, for added clarification.

Comment: I say "curly braces", "square braces" or "square brackets" and of course "parentheses". I have not normally used "angle brackets", but I might pick that one up because it's easier to say, and more meaningful in that context than "lt,gt"

Comment: _Curly brackets_ is the term used in linguistics for one particular usage of '{ }'; this contrasts with _square brackets_ '[ ]'. In fact, "Curly Bracketts" was a pseudonym used for some satirical fake linguistic papers.

Comment: Unicode calls the symbol "LEFT CURLY BRACKET"

Comment: For what it's worth, TeX distinguishes (but many novice TeXers incorrectly don't) between the less-than greater-than signs `<>` and the angle brackets `\langle\rangle`.

Answer (score 65):

**curly braces** (or 'braces' for short)

This is more common than curly brackets, to design blocks in programming languages.

See [Why curly braces? (WebArchive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100903224911/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327387/why-curly-braces/) for more.

> Curly braces are one means of denoting a lexical scope. Lexical scopes are blocks of code from which names do not escape

See also:

- [history and use of parentheses in programming languages, from the beginning of programming to the present day](http://www.gavilan.edu/csis/languages/parentheses.html).
- [wordiq definition](http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Bracket).

Comment: Actually, I refer to them just as 'braces'. 'curly' is more a disambiguation for 'brackets'. And yes [nohat](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat), I just realized wordiq is only a copy of the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets_.7B_.7D). Again...

Comment: I say curly brace, because where I went through school, brackets ALWAYS meant "()", while we had square braces: "[]", angle braces or less/bigger than: "<>", and curly braces: "{}". That was just the most common usage, some people called "()" either braces or brackets, so the important thing was the qualifier on the type of brace for anything other than "()".

Comment: I always took "brackets" to mean "{}", "square brackets" to mean "[]", and "parentheses" to mean "()". "Braces" are what I had on my teeth. (Now that I interact with programmers more, I accept "curly braces" and "curly brackets" as a means of disambiguation.)

Answer (score 44):

I always thought `{` was officially a brace.

`[` is a bracket

`(` is a parenthesis

With "bracket" also referring to any one of the three.

Comment: This is the terminology that I have always used (in Australia). Further to this, I tend to refer to the angle brackets, < >, as chevrons but I have come across some people who do not understand that term.

Comment: I thought chevrons were ⟪ ⟫

Comment: As a fellow Australian, that's the definitions that I was taught; however in a programming or more everyday context it might cause confusion. As has been mentioned in another answer, 'curly bracket' is accepted, if not 'correct'.

Answer (score 26):

The Chicago Manual of Style refers to them as "braces".

> **6.102**
>   "Braces, {}, often called curly brackets, provide yet another option for enclosing data and are used in various ways in certain
>   programming languages. They are also used in mathematical and other
>   specialized writing (see, e.g., 12.28). They are not interchangeable
>   with parentheses or brackets. See the example phrases throughout
>   chapter 5 for one possible use of braces."
>   http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch06/ch06_sec102.html
>
> **12.28**
>   Set notation Braces are used to delimit the elements of a set, and other delimiters should not be substituted. For example,
>   {a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...a<sub>n</sub>}
>   http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch12/ch12_sec028.html

You will find this use of the word "brace" to be supported by dictionary definitions.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brace?show=1&t=1341592270
http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/brace
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brace

Comment: This is the one answer I'm upvoting, because it has the virtue of being fairly authoritative (which IMHO is what was meant by "professional name"). However, I can't imagine a context where I'd call them that, as the vast majority of my readers/listeners would be uncertian which glyphs I'm talking about exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote T.E.D.   As a programmer, I call them "squirrelly brackets" because it's fun, and everyone knows what I am talking about. However, yes, I was looking for the "most professional" name for the marks.

Comment: @Torrence: If you're looking for more fun names, I had a grade school teacher who playfully called them "Alfred Hitchcocks" because of their resemblance to the [profile](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_o9OdjxY26rU/RsDGodvFDSI/AAAAAAAACdY/zQsQl4bu_xE/s400/alfred-hitchcock-collection.jpg) of the famous director's face. But, no, that's hardly the "most professional" term.

Comment: @J.R. I love it.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if this counts as the most professional name, but the Unicode standard refers to them as

> LEFT CURLY BRACKET (was previously OPENING CURLY BRACKET)

and

> RIGHT CURLY BRACKET (was previously CLOSING CURLY BRACKET)

---

from [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf):

`LEFT CURLY BRACKET
= opening curly bracket (1.0)
= left brace`

Comment: A reference link would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Technically: “[]” are called brackets, “()” are called parentheses and “{}” are called braces.  But in the real world these terms are used interchangeably so, to avoid confusion, be sure to make it 100% clear that you mean “{}”.

Answer (score 5):

In my line of work (software development) we call them curly brackets or braces. These seem fairly canonical:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Braces

Answer (score 3):

The unicode standard uses "LEFT CURLY BRACKET" to describe this symbol: http://www.decodeunicode.org/u+007B

Answer (score 2):

I've always called them gullwings as this is clearly the coolest name for them.  Curly brackets is probably the best if you want people to know what you're talking about.

Comment: The symbols « and », mentioned above, are called guillemets, and function as quotation marks in some languages.  See the Wikipedia article on "guillemets" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a java course then they are braces. See for example http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc6.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of comments about brackets and braces, but I think your question was seeking confirmation of "curly". Will Macmillan dictionary do?

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/curly-brackets

Comment: That link does little for the "more professional name" part of the question, because it labels *curly brackets* as informal.