# What is the common name for brackets, braces, and parentheses?

Tags: parentheses, square-brackets, braces

I need to name a variable containing `()[]{}`, what is the common name for all of them?

Two side questions:

- parentheses is plural, or singular, or both?
- is abbreviating it as `parens` understandable?

Comment: Related: [Bracket vs brace](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/) and [What is the most professional name for “squiggly bracket”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't really an established generic for them; if I had to say something, I'd probably say *enclosing glyphs*.  Trying to use "bracket" as a generic doesn't really work because "brackets" usually specifically means `()` in British English and `[]` in American English.

Seeing that you're naming a variable, I would probably go with `$enclosures`.

Parentheses is a plural; the singular is parenthesis.

"Parens" is usual and understandable, yes.

Comment: In British English, `[]` are "square brackets" and `{}` are "curly brackets", so they're all types of brackets, so to speak.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Oh yes, indeed! I really wonder when/how *parentheses* came into American usage. It's such a long and cumbersome word!

Comment: @Jimi Oke : I dont know but as the french word is the same ( "parenthèse") i can guess :D

Comment: I hear { called curly braces a lot, rather than curly brackets.

Comment: @Martin: I and many others call them simply "braces", adding "curly" only if I'm not sure the listener will understand me.

Comment: @Jimi Oke, “parenthesis” http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29 originally referred to words contained within the enclosing marks, and then later came to also refer to the marks themselves.

Comment: Note that the 'bracket = `()` in British English' is likely to die quite quickly in coming decades, given the increasing ubiquity of programming as a Core Working Skill, and given the universality of referfing to `[]` as brackets and `()` as parentheses in programming contexts.

Comment: They are *paired delimiter* characters.

Answer (score 14):

You can call all of them braces or call all of them brackets.

I have heard

- `[]` called *brackets*, *square brackets*, and *square braces*;
- `{}` called *braces*, *curly braces*, and *curly brackets*.
- `()` called *parentheses*

While it's true I have never heard `()` referred to as "curved braces" or "curved brackets" or anything like that, it is fine to lump them in with other "enclosing punctuation" as other answers and comments suggest.

I specifically recommend against *enclosing glyphs* because it is a little too snooty, as if you're some kind of English show-off trying to talk to programmers about programming.  I don't mind calling these symbols *enclosures*, though in programming contexts, this term might be a little too close to *closures*, which are something else.

Don't forget that `<>` are also common enclosures, referred to as *angle brackets* or *angle braces*.

Finally, so that this answer addresses everything asked, I'll reiterate that `()` are *parentheses*; one of them is a *parenthesis*; and that these can be freely shortened to *parens* and *paren*, respectively, especially when talking to programmers.

Comment: Very good answer. One of the thoughts informing my own answer above is that we have the terms "square brackets" and "angle brackets." Although you never see the term "curved brackets," it's very clear from the above that these things are all considered "brackets" of a type.

Comment: This is clearly the best answer.

Answer (score 9):

These can be called "brackets."

Regarding the side questions, "marks of parenthesis" is the standard term, and parentheses is possible, but a bit breezy. "Parens" is the usual abbreviation.

Answer (score 9):

In every IDE I've used, the concept of highlighting or validating matching enclosures has been referred to as *brace-matching*, so I would suggest *brace* as a candidate to cover all of the glyphs you mention.

A *brace* of things refers to a pair of something (the origin is from hunting), and is synonymous with *pair*.

Comment: It's also used specifically to refer to `{}`, unfortunately.

Comment: @chaos: The symbol, `{`, is a brace and it's only referred to as such when it is used to indicate a relationship between two or more items, e.g. a linear system of equations, a system of music staves, etc. *Braces* would usually mean the pair, `{}`.

Comment: @Jimi Oke I was brought up on the term "curly braces" for `{}`. Funny how oddly annoying it is to hear another term for this symbol!

Comment: @chaos: Not really. Anyway, "glyph" is so broad as to be unusable.

Comment: @Robusto: I assure you it is, specifically among computer programmers following American linguistic conventions.  Regarding your feedback, I'm not proposing *glyph*, I'm proposing *enclosing glyph*.

Comment: @chaos: And I have always heard "braces" as I mentioned in my answer. I have never heard "enclosing glyph" ... but this is water over the dam or under the bridge or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of "Enclosing glyphs", which sounds like something a technical standards organization would come up with to classify the symbols for something like Unicode, I'd suggest "grouping symbols." "Grouping symbols" may imply a mathematical usage, but I doubt that the association with math is very strong.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia article on delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Bracket_delimiters) gives "**Bracket delimiters** (also **block delimiters**, **region delimiters** or **balanced delimiters**)..."

Answer (score 2):

PairedPunctuationMarks is the clearest that I can come up with.  However, as a programmer I would strongly urge you to name variables based on how they're used instead of what they are.  It makes for easier to read code.  So, if these symbols are going to be, say, part of the legal ways to delimit a certain kind of token in your code, a name like LegalUserInputDelimitersForFooRegex might be a better variable.

Comment: I like `PairedPunctuationMarks`, but it's quite long. Btw., the purpose of my var is to determine if a char is a `PairedPunctuationMark` and to find its counterpart if so.

Comment: That's why we have IDEs with auto-complete.  If this were my code it'd probably be CharsToCheckForClosingChar or something.  Enjoy!

Comment: Why not just use paired marks?