# General term for punctuation that surrounds a word or phrase?

Tags: punctuation, phrase-requests, terminology, typography

Is there a general term for punctuation that surrounds a word or phrase? Something that includes [brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) and [quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), but there may be other types of punctuation, formal or otherwise, that have the same appearance.

Let me give some examples, and their purpose:

- Parentheses `()` to separate supplementary information from the main sentence: *Sen. John McCain (R., Arizona) spoke at length.*
- Quotes `""` to indicate a group of words referring to a singular entity, such as the title of a work: *David Bowie's "Space Oddity"*
- [Dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) `—` to show a break in thought, similar to parentheses: *You are the friend—the only friend—who offered to help me.*
- [Markup annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) used for purposes other than reading, for example as instructions for printing/presentation: *In Markdown, surrounding a phrase in asterisks renders it in italics*

What term would you use to cover these in general? I see a few possibilities:

- **Brackets** which covers most of them but I feel it doesn't include quotes
- **Bookends** since that's what they look like, but unless I use it in context it's not clear what I'm referring to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with **delimiters**.  While other things could be considered delimiters, such as (unpaired) periods delimiting sentences, I think the word suitably captures the essence of what you're after.

As mentioned in [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14252), *enclosures* might be an alternative.

Comment: Or *delimiter pairs*, *pairs of delimiters*?

Answer (score 0):

I would call it **bracketing punctuation**.

For reference, see the following definition of *bracket (v.)* according to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bracket):

> to be located at each side of (something)

Each of the punctuation pairs you mentioned are located one at each side of some word or phrase; hence, *bracketing* punctuation.

Comment: This might be a good choice, but can you provide an appropriate dictionary definition of _bracketing_ to clarify to readers why it is suitable in the context of punctuation?