# How to describe braces, brackets, parentheses?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I have this term:

> ((x ,y, z))

and I need to describe in words that the **x** in this term should be outside the bars? 
Is this correct? *outside the bars*?

> x ((y,z))

The position of the x doesn't matter, it could be also behind:

> ((y,z)) x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These - ( ) - are called 'parentheses' in English punctuation, but in maths they are called 'brackets'. In this situation I would say, 'x is outside the brackets'.

Comment: I thought brackets are this ones []

Comment: I would call [] 'square brackets'. (In American English, [] are called just 'brackets' though.) The terminology used changes from context. In literature, () would be parenthesis; in maths, I would call it brackets. Similarly, {} in maths would be 'curly brackets' while in programming they would be called 'braces'. Have you heard of the term ['BODMAS'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BODMAS) in maths, which is used to denote the order of operations? That's an an example of the term 'brackets' being used for ()

Comment: [Bracket vs brace](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/) ◊ [What is the common name for brackets, braces, and parentheses?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14252/) ◊ [What is the most professional name for “squiggly bracket”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302/)