# What's the name of a large curly brace?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, punctuation, braces

I'm looking for a particular element for a project and I'm not sure what to google. What's the name of that large brace that is used to group items together? A crude Paint rendition:

[image: left curly brace { spanning 3 lines]

Comment: You're pushing it now! We'll be arguing over whether this is a left brace or a left medial brace.

Comment: You yourself have already called it “a large curly brace”; why would you need something else?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [302](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302/what-is-the-most-professional-name-for-squiggly-bracket)! This question is about what you call a single large curly brace that is used as a grouping mechanism to span multiple lines. I've wanted to know the answer to that question for many years myself.

Comment: In music, the large curly braces that span and join several staves are called ***accolades***. The usage and meaning of this is exactly the same as in your picture, but as far as I know, the term is only used when referring specifically to musical notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Braces or curly bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Braces_or_curly_brackets_.7B_.7D) according to Wikipedia

It is called a *Side brace* in Visio

[image: Side Brace]

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not mention the particular usage of braces that the OP specifies. How in-house 'side brace' is is debatable, but I imagine there isn't a more generally used term. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/side-brace-around-image-with-underbrace shows a sidebrace and an underbrace.

Comment: I do not know of a specific name for a _curly bracket that is used to group things_ other than _curly bracket/brace used to group things_

Comment: There are braces other than side braces and underbraces (and possibly top braces). OP specifies 'large curly bracket' as opposed to 'curly bracket', so I assume he means multi-row or multi-column usages. He also asks what type of brace, not bracket. [Ah - his edit confirms this.] The Wikipedia article doesn't mention these. Your diagram is fine (and was upvoted).